# Azure virtual machines are not listed in azure portal

Tags: azure

I am losing the list of all virtual machines in windows azure portal. I have 4 active virtual machines and most of the time I login to azure portal I do not see any virtual machine. After I ran powershell commands to check the connection the connection returned all 4 virtual machines.

I am not sure if there is some issue with my azure account or others do see the same problem. Does anyone know what is the issue?

Comment: You should contact Microsoft support

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this problem is related with your Azure Subscription. There is a known issue with Windows Azure Portal where some of the services are not listed with certain Subscriptions and the issue is intermittent. If you still see the problem your best bet is to contact Azure Support team and let them know about this issue. Or just wait a while and the problem should be resolved.